# When converting a string to an expression using ToExpression[], how to prevent the result from evaluating?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following string:

```
"{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}"
```

And I want to convert it to expression(s). Directly apply `ToExpression` only gives the last, i.e., `{f[{x, 1 + y}]}`. How to get the whole list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the documentation of `ToExpression` to find its 3rd argument, and use

```
ToExpression["{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}", InputForm, Hold]
```

to prevent evaluation.

Several functions that either convert expressions or extract parts (`Extract`, `Level`, etc.) have an option to wrap the extracted part in an arbitrary function.  A common use is to wrap them in `Hold`, preventing evaluation.

---

**EDIT:**  Note that your expression is not a list.  It's a `CompoundExpression`.  You might be looking for

```
ToExpression["{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}", InputForm, Hold] /. CompoundExpression -> List // ReleaseHold
```

Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and where you got the string from?

Comment: After I do that, I got `Hold` in front of the expressions. How to get rid of the Hold after this? Use `Apply`?

Comment: Use `ReleaseHold` to remove Hold when you want the expression to evaluate. Or, use `HoldForm` instead of `Hold` - this works like Hold but doesn't display.

Comment: @littleEinstein If you get rid of `Hold`, the expression will evaluate and you'll end up with `{f[{x, 1 + y}]}` again.  I think you might have a misunderstanding about what `;` is.  Please tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is simply go from the String `"{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}"` to an Expression `{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}`. I am writing some computer-generated Mathematica code

Comment: @littleEinstein As I already said, `ToExpression["{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}"]` *does* return `{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}`, but it immediately evaluates to `f[{x, 1 + y}]`.  It's the same as not being able to have `1+1`.

Comment: @littleEinstein If you generate code, it's probably better to use held expression (`Hold`) than strings.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't know that.  Though the docs say, "Since Version 3.0 (released in 1996), ToHeldExpression has been superseded by ToExpression."

Answer (score 1):

Actually `ToExpression` is converting the whole string to an expression as you would expect. In the following example

```
In[1]:= ToExpression["a=1;b=2"]
Out[1]= 2

In[2]:= a
Out[2]= 1
```

you can see that the first part `a=1` was evaluated correctly as part of the `CompoundExpression`.

What you probably want is to convert your expressions separated by semicolons to a list of expressions. You can use StringSplit for that:

```
In[3]:= ToExpressionList[s_String] := ToExpression /@ StringSplit[s, ";"]

In[4]:= ToExpressionList["x;y"]
Out[4]= {x,y}
```

**Edit :** 
It looks like you' re trying to use the semicolon as a list
separator.In Mathematica you would have to use `,` for this.So you
could also achieve what you want by substituting `,` for `;` in
your string and then applying `ToExpression` afterwards:

```
In[20] := ToExpression @
            StringReplace[
              "{f[{-1 + x, y}]; f[{1 + x, y}]; f[{x, 1 + y}]}",
              ";" -> ","
            ]


Out[20] = {f({x-1,y}),f({x+1,y}),f({x,y+1})}
```

Comment: However, I do want to keep the `;` after `ToExpression`

Comment: ok, now i see! Then i misinterpreted your question. Szabolcs gave the  right answer then.

Comment: I must mention that using strings in this context is fragile in general, and also in this case in particular. Semicolon is also a part of `/;` (`Condition`) operator, with obvious consequences.